# Magento 2 - Call phtml in helper

Tags: magento2, phtml, helper

I have found multiple threads related to calling helper function in .phtml.

But I have a case where I need to call phtml file in helper and return HTML.

I have used this code:

```
//Where $this->_resultPageFactory is the object of \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
$resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
$html = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock("Vendor\Module\Block\Index")
            ->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::index.phtml")
            ->toHtml();
return $html;
```

It is working fine, but the problem is, it is effecting other stuff like Product title, Media gallery etc (it is changed after using above code)

So, how can I call .pthml from helper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. Copied from gift-card module (Enterprise)

For variables in constructor

```
protected $_layout;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
    ...
) {
    $this->_layout = $layout;
    ...
}
```

Now in any of the function where you want to call phtml, use this:

```
$block = $this->_layout->createBlock(\Vendor\Module\Block\Index::class);
$block->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::index.phtml");
return $block;
```

Comment: hello @Shoaib Thnk you for your effort but in my case it is not working I need to get phtml file data using helper can you please look in to this code.   $block = $this->_layout->createBlock(\Vendor\Module\Block\Index::class);
$block->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::index.phtml")->toHtml();

Comment: Please share your constructor code

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
$block = $this->_layout->createBlock(\Vendor\Module\Block\Index::class);
$block->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::index.phtml");
return $block;
```

Where `$this->_layout` is the instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface`

Comment: My answer is almost same, but +1 for your efforts